# Find a linear functional $T$ on $C([-1,1])$ for which there is no $f \in C([-1,1])$ such that $|T f |=\| T \|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

***Problem:* Find a linear functional $T$ on $C([-1,1])$ for which there is no $f \in C([-1,1])$ such that $|T f |=\| T \|$**

Anyone can give me a hint or even a solution? Thanks

Comment: This is false. For any $f \neq 0$ simply pick $$g= \frac{||T||}{|Tf|}f$$ Maybe you have to modify your question.

Comment: You have to specify what norm you have on $C([-1, 1])$.

Comment: It doesn't specify, I assume is max norm

Comment: You probably also want $\|f\|=1$ in your question.

Comment: As suggested by @Aweygann, the actual problem must be: Show there exists a continuous linear functional $T$ on $C=C([-1,1])$ such that for every $f\in C$ with $\|f\|=1,$ $|T(f)| < \|T\|.$

Comment: You might be right, but I double checked my paper and what I wrote here,it was the problem. Any tips in this case then?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is: Show there exists a continuous linear functional $T$ on $C=C([-1,1])$ such that for every $f\in C$ with $\|f\|=1,$ $|T(f)| < \|T\|.$ Hint: Consider

$$T(f) = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,x\,dx.$$

Note: My previous answer was unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one.

$Tf= \frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1 f(t) -f(0) dt$

Here RHS is considered as a constant function.

Observe:

1. For $g \in C[-1,1]$,  $|\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 g(t) dt|\le\|g\|$ with equality if and only if $g$ is constant. Therefore,

$$ \|Tf \| \le \frac 12 \|f(t)-f(0)\|\le \|f\|.$$

The second inequality is due to triangle inequality. By the above claim, the first is an equality if and only if $f$ is a constant, in which case the LHS is zero. Therefore, $\|Tf\|<1$ whenever $\|f\|=1$.

2. Why is $\|T\|=1$ ? Think of $f_n(t)=2\min (1,n|t|)-1$.